# OSX OAuth redirect_uri in WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, oauth

I'm trying to authenticate an OSX app via OAuth - specifically, using the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) .
I've setup an app with Instagram - have the client ID and secret - but I'm unsure of how to deal with the `redirect_url` and how to retrieve the access_token, once authenticated.

So far I've just a simple WebView which loads the login page...

```
[[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=THECLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code"]]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement the method `- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame` from the [WebFrameLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) informal delegate. Then (in Interface Builder) wire up the outlet `frameLoadDelegate` from the WebView to an instance of the class where you implemented `- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame`. Example implementation:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame {
    NSString *currentURL = [[[[webFrame dataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"Our WebView just loaded: %@", currentURL);
    if ([currentURL hasPrefix:yourRedirectURIString]) {
        // We are at the redirect URI!
    }
}
```